# Mobilefirst 8.0 javascript SQL adapter with bluemix MongoDB database connectivity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters

I have to develop the application using mongoDB with mobilefirst sql javascript adapter. i have an idea about normal database sql adapter connectivity but i don't have idea how to create bluemix mongoDB with mobilefirst 8.0 javascript-sql adapter.

how to configure the MongoDB connectivity in adapter.xml file? and I created maven javascript sql adapter in my local machine as well.

advanced thanks

Comment: How would you use MongoDB is it wasn't through MobileFirst ? You would have used REST APIs to access it?

Comment: do you have any idea about that.how to create database and make it restful.i was not able to seeing right document in bluemix

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a noSQL DB and holds JSON like data.You should use HTTP adapter instead of SQL adapter to meet your requirement. 
Invoke the REST endpoints of your MongoDB service in your Javascript HTTP adapter.

Also, note that IBM Bluemix gives you Compose for MongoDB.

Refer to the documentation available [here](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/compose/).

[MongoDB](https://www.compose.com/articles/curated-content-mongodb/)

Answer (score 0):

As Vivn has suggested, you can use HTTP adapters to connect to MongoDB.

You would need to make your MongoDB RESTful. You can use one of [these options](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#rest-interfaces) to make it RESTful.

So, this could be a way to do it:

1. Setup MongoDB database.
2. Expose MongoDB as a RESTful API. If you use [Compose for MongoDB](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-mongodb/) on IBM Bluemix, then 
   [this article](https://www.compose.com/articles/building-instant-restful-apis-with-mongodb-and-restheart/) shows deploying RESTHeart as a docker instance to connect to MongoDB deployed on Compose. The REST API can be secured using Basic Authentication. You could choose to run this docker container as IBM Bluemix Containers as well.
3. Use HTTP Adapters to connect to MongoDB via REST API.
   [This blog sample](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/cloudant/) describes how to connect `MobileFirst 8.0 HTTP Adapter` to `Cloudant` - which is also a noSQL database. You can use the same approach to develop your adapter.